# How to check if email address exists in real world or not, by sending a request to smtp server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I am getting an error in smtp connection when I send a request to stmp server.

```
IList<MXServer> list = new List<MXServer>();

foreach (string line in result.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    if (line.Contains("MX preference =") && line.Contains("mail exchanger ="))
        {
        MXServer mxServer = new MXServer();
        mxServer.Preference = Int(GetStringBetween(line, "MX preference = ", ","));
        mxServer.MailExchanger = GetStringFrom(line, "mail exchanger = ");

        list.Add(mxServer);
    }
}
```

Comment: The standard way to do this is, send them an email with a time dependent token and get them to validate it via a web request. Think about it, when is the last time you have filled out a form and it said, sorry thats not your real email address, YOU LIED!

Comment: Your implementation should be more around "Verify email address"? Once user provides one.

Answer (score 1):

By using SMTP, you can ask the server if it has the user. SMTP is a text based protocol. But there are some important points:

1. Every server checks for spam, either this or that way. So your IP address must be a **CLEAN** one. (not to be listed in spam lists)
2. Even your IP is clean, repeatedly asking for an address may result your ip to be **BANNED**
3. Most service providers bans smtp ports. So you may need a static IP address.
4. Most servers check for reverse DNS record for inbound connections. So you may need a reverse DNS (`PTR`) record.
5. You may need an `SPF` record.
6. There are 2 ways to ask an SMTP server: a. `VRFY` command  b. `RCPT TO`
7. Most servers are not replying `VRFY` because of security reasons.

So here is an SMTP session example:

```
C: MAIL FROM:<mail@samlogic.com>
S: 250 OK
C: RCPT TO:<john@mail.com>
S: 250 OK
C: RCPT TO:<peggy@mail.com>
S: 250 OK
```

Basically if you get `250 ...` answer for a `RCPT TO` command 90% the email address is ok. Then you can abort the connection.

Comment: How do you do that in C#? I search in google but not found yet.

Comment: @Souza you can make a tcp connection. The server will reply in clear text. Then parse the answer.

Comment: Thank's. I tried telnet to do tcp connection (WINDOWS SO) and gmail accepted at port 25. And It accepted RCPT command.